# Communication between two not directly connected ViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegation

I'd like to let ViewController F communciate with ViewController C. 
They are arranged like this: 
Navigation Controller A embeds ViewController B, which presents ViewController C inside of a container view. 
There's a segue from ViewController B to NavigationController D, that embeds ViewController E and ViewController F (segue between E and F).

My current working solution is the following: Build up a delegation "path" between the necessary ViewControllers: ViewController F delegates to ViewController E, which delegates to ViewController B, that finally delegates the information to ViewController C.
It feels like there must be an easier way to do this. 
Can you recommend one? Maybe hand over ViewController C inside of the "segue path" to ViewController F to set up a direct delegation between C and F?

Thanks!

Comment: What does `communicate` mean? Run methods? Pass data back and forth? Respond to events? Your question is unclear. There are many possible methods like singletons, delegation, `NSNotificationCenter`.

Comment: In my case communication means: F needs to be able to trigger a method of C and also pass data along the way. Sorry for the unclear question and thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use NSNotification

**In ViewController F:**

```
- (void)sendData {
    // Fire the notification
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ReceivedData" 
                                                        object:nil];   
}
```

**In ViewController C:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                            selector:@selector(receivedDataNotification:) 
                                                name:@"ReceivedData" 
                                              object:nil];
}

- (void)receivedDataNotification:(id)object {
    NSLog(@"Received Data!");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me into the right direction! I now use     `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ReceivedData" object:self userInfo:userInfo];`